# Is there a way to copy Win 10 built in apps such as Microsoft Edge to another windows?

Tags: microsoft-edge

So what I am trying to say is that I am using **Win10** in a laptop that has a **Microsoft Edge version 44.18**. And I want to copy this version to my desktop PC and I have found all the file but when I run the **Edge Browser** from those files it won't run. Is there a way I can copy this browser and run it. I am providing the picture of the directory and the files
Thank in advance. ;)

[image: Edge Browser]

This are the file related the Edge Browser:
[image: img]

when I run it nothing it won't run not even as administrator: 
[image: img]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply 

Answer (score 0):

Which Windows OS version and Edge browser version are you using on the desktop PC? The Microsoft Edge 44.18 version is the Windows OS 1903 build in apps, to use this version Edge browser, you could upgrade the Windows OS version to 1903 version. In my opinion, I'm not suggesting you directly copy the Edge folder to other devices.

If you just want to make some test using the Edge 44.18 version on the desktop PC, and not want to change the desktop OS, I suggest you could download a [free Windows 10 virtual machines](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) on the desktop PC and use the Edge 44.18 version.